# Export Firewall rules to excel using powershell v2

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to consolidate the output of the command below in an excel sheet

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name = all | out-file .\rules.txt
```

Currently the output of command above looks something like this

```
  Rule Name:                            Remote Assistance (PNRP-Out)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Enabled:                              Yes
 Direction:                            Out
 Profiles:                             Domain,Private
 Grouping:                             Remote Assistance
 LocalIP:                              Any
 RemoteIP:                             Any
 Protocol:                             UDP
 LocalPort:                            Any
 RemotePort:                           Any
 Edge traversal:                       No
 Action:                               Allow
```

I need to have this in an excel file like

```
 Rule Name                      Enabled  Direction  Profiles        Grouping           LocalIP      RemoteIP    Protocol    RemotePort  Edge Transversal    Actions

 Remote Assistance (PNRP-Out)    Yes        Out     Domain,Private  Remote Assistance    Any          Any        UDP         Any         No                  Allow
```

Is there any way to do this. This is to be done ONLY on poweshell v2. No other modules can be imported. This should be done for each rule that the netsh command outputs.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Would/could your life be easier if you made the data into csv which Excel can open?  That would be an easy transformation.

Comment: Parsing the strings is the real challenge, once you have an array of objects with the right properties outputting to CSV or Excel aren't really that different.  As far as parsing the string goes I just played around with it a bit and I couldn't come up with an easy way to do it but I'd say to start with a loop that divides the string array into rules and then parse it from there looping through it and using regex or indexes of spaces to grab the data, can also probably just grab the last bunch of characters in the string and do a `.Trim()` to clear the whitepace but that's a little sloppy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fetch rules using com object and convert to csv (csv can be opened with excel ) like this:

```
$Rules=(New-object –comObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2).rules
$Rules | export-csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @Matt I have tested this with v2 and it's working fine

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!! I did try exporting but I guess we needed the comObject stuff